# How to write code insert multiple data to database Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to fill and insert a lot of duplicates into the database. In the same table But i don't know how to write code on the controller. **Laravel**

**html**

```
<table class="table ">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td width="5%"><center>ลำดับ</center></td>
            <td width="20%"><center>เลขบัญชี</center></td>
            <td width="40%"><center>ชื่อบัญชี</center></td>
            <td width="35%"><center>จำนวนเงิน</center></td>
            <td width="10%"><center></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="resultbody">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Script**

```
$(function () {
    $('.add').click(function () {
        var n = ($('.resultbody tr').length - 0) + 1;
        var tr =
                '<tr><td width="5%" class="no" name="svae_no"><center>' + n + '</center></td>' +
                '<td width="20%"><input type="text" class="name form-control" name="rows[0][save_id]"></td>'+
                '<td width="40%"><input type="text" class="fname form-control" name="rows[0][save_name]"></td>'+
                '<td width="35%"><input type="text" class="fname form-control" name="rows[0][save_money]"></td>'+
                '<td width="10%"><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" value="x"></td></tr>';
        $('.resultbody').append(tr);
    });
    $('.resultbody').delegate('.delete', 'click', function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
```

**controller add data**

```
public function add(Request $request){$save_no = $request->input('save_no');
    $save_id = $request->input('save_id');
    $save_name = $request->input('save_name');
    $save_money = $request->input('save_money');$data_save=array(
        'mem_died_id'=>$mem_died_id,
        'save_no'=>$save_no,
        'save_id'=>$save_id,
        'save_name'=>$save_name,
        'save_money'=>$save_money);
    DB::table('died_save')->insert($data_save);return back();
```

Comment: where did you declared `$mem_died_id` ???

Answer (score 0):

If we work on big project and then we maybe require to add multiple rows on database using laravel eloquent. Laravel provide insert method for bulk records create on db.

In bellow example you can see i use multidimensional $myItems array variable and that insert multiple records same time using DB::insert(). So let's see and try this.

Example:

```
$myItems = [
            ['title'=>'HD Topi','description'=>'It solution stuff'],
            ['title'=>'HD Topi 2','description'=>'It solution stuff 2'],
            ['title'=>'HD Topi 3','description'=>'It solution stuff 3']
        ];


DB::table("items")->insert($myItems);
```